# CountDownTimer in android - how to restart it

Tags: android, counter

I have to restart a CountDownTimer. I read a lot of question here but no one of the answer helped me.
When I use the following code

```
if(Const.counter != null){
    Const.counter.cancel();
    Const.counter = null;
}


Const.counter = new CustomTimerTask(Const.currentLevel.timeGoal * 1000,1000);
Const.counter.start();
```

I started a new counter but the old one also continues work.  Please help me solve it.

Comment: try to use cornometer ...u can esailt reset

Comment: You can just:
timer.cancel() and then timer.start()

Answer (score 14):

You can realize it by cancelling and restarting. The following example should work.

```
CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(500, 1000) {

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        isCounterRunning = false;
    }
};


boolean isCounterRunning  = false;

private void yourOperation() {
    if( !isCounterRunning ){
        isCounterRunning = true;
        mCountDownTimer.start();
    }
    else{
        mCountDownTimer.cancel(); // cancel
        mCountDownTimer.start();  // then restart
    }

}
```

Comment: mCountDownTimer.cancel(); // not reset the counter

Answer (score 8):

I did some different trick here. Hope this will help you.

```
if (myCountDownTimer != null) {
            myCountDownTimer.cancel();
        }
        myCountDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(10000, 500);
        myCountDownTimer.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

Just call again the `start()` method:

```
CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        this.start(); //start again the CountDownTimer
    }
};
```

Comment: isnt this an endless loop?

Comment: @SairajSawant Yes, but he was asking how to restart it. If you want to start it somewhere else you just need to call `cdt.start()`

Answer (score 1):

coutdown timer for quiz

```
 if(countDownTimer!=null)
            {
                countDownTimer.cancel();
                countDownTimer.start();
                }
            else {
               countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

                    public void onTick(long l) {
                        mtimer.setText("remaining time" + l / 1000);//mtime is a textview
                    }

                    public void onFinish() {//here mnext is the button from which we can get next question.
                        mnext.performClick();//this is used to perform clik automatically

                    }
                }.start();
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
private fun startTimer() {
    var timeInMilliSeconds = 11000L
    val countDownTimer: CountDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(timeInMilliSeconds, 1000) {
        override fun onFinish() {
            Timber.d("Times Up!")
            setupResult("")
            this.cancel()
            timeInMilliSeconds = 11000L
            this.start()
        }

        override fun onTick(p0: Long) {
            val seconds = (p0 / 1000) % 60
            Timber.d("Timer: $p0")
            timer?.text = "$seconds"
        }
    }
    countDownTimer.start()
}
```