# How to wait for a few seconds between text changed in Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm using [MaterialChipsInput](https://github.com/pchmn/MaterialChipsInput) (although it does not matter what is the component I'm using). I have the following code:

```
chipsInput.addChipsListener(new ChipsInput.ChipsListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChipAdded(ChipInterface chip, int newSize) {}

    @Override
    public void onChipRemoved(ChipInterface chip, int newSize) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence text) {
        if (text != null && text.toString().contains(",") && text.toString().length() > 1) {
            final String tag = Utils.capitalizeFully(text.toString().replaceAll(",","").trim());
            if (!(tag.isEmpty())) {
                chipsInput.addChip(tag, null);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Basically, it add tags to `chipsInput` every time user enters a comma. The problem is that the user will have to end with a comma in order to add it as a chip. I would like to add a timer for 5 seconds and if there is no changes after those 5 seconds, it will add that chip to the `chipsInput`. What would be the easiest way to do it?

Comment: `Thread.sleep(5000)` in try catch

Comment: @AniketSahrawat that's not gonna work because `onTextChanged` will be called again and you'll just have another sleep. Changed my title a bit so it will be easier to understand.

Comment: That needs to be executed in a different thread and checked for input. But if you aren't familiar with concurrency then don't do it because it will create more harm than ease.

Comment: I do understand how threads work. The problem is that `ChipsInput` is a third party so I'm not the one that handles the execution of `onTextChanged`. I override the method and somehow I need to follow user's changes.

Comment: Use a `runnable` with `Handler`

Comment: The `Chip` extends `AppCompatTextView` extends `TextView` which supports a `onFocusChanged`; so extend `Chip` and implement the `onFocusChanged` callback - if losing focus is the criteria needed (rather than time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its `onTextChanged` is called from `onTextChanged` of the Chip's `EditText` as declared [here](https://github.com/pchmn/MaterialChipsInput/blob/c1e7aa9997e422a4d7671c7642c73fb3838f42c6/library/src/main/java/com/pchmn/materialchips/adapter/ChipsAdapter.java#L158) in the library to which you cannot do much. So, here's I'm pointing out a solution using `CountDownTimer`.

Why a CountDownTimer? Because You can reset the time back to 0 if user types again under 5 seconds. You can also do it using a `Handler` and reset it again as done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38701503/8244632).

1. Declare `mCountDownTimer` a global variable as :

   ```
   CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
   ```
2. Declare `countDownFunction()` as :

   ```
   private void countDownFunction(String chipText) {
       if(mCountDownTimer != null) 
           mCountDownTimer.cancel(); // Cancels the CountDown

       mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
           @Override
           public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
               //Called after every delay of the above second parameter as a ticking count down
               //Current delay is 1 second as 1000 passed above
           }

           @Override
           public void onFinish() {
               //This will only be called on successful five second delay
               chipsInput.addChip(chipText, null); //chipText is the parameter passed to this function
               //You may want to clear the Chip `EditText` here
           }
       };
       mCountDownTimer.start(); // Restarts the CountDown
    }
   ```
3. Call your `countDownFunction()` from the `onTextChanged` and pass the text to it as :

   ```
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence text) {
        if (text != null && text.toString().length() > 1) {
            if(text.toString().contains(",")){
                final String tag = Utils.capitalizeFully(text.toString().replaceAll(",","").trim());
                if (!(tag.isEmpty())) {
                    chipsInput.addChip(tag, null);
                }
            }
            else
                countDownFunction(Utils.capitalizeFully(text.toString().trim()));
        }
    }
   ```

Now, to improve this, you can use `AsyncTask` or Handler with `runnable` thread. There are many ways to do this, there are many ways to handle the async operation to ensure smooth running app.

But, this gives you the idea - What's happening here is every time a text is entered without comma `,`, this function is called and it either starts the count down if not previously started or restarts it because of which the `onFinish()` of the count down will only be called if it passes the 5 second time and then it will add the chip.

**Edit :** Now, the resetting of the timer will work better. You can still look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19997588/countdowntimer-in-android-how-to-restart-it).

Comment: You are awesome :)