# how to start again the CountDownTimer in java

Tags: java, android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19A4L.png)

does anyone knows how to start again the CountDownTimer? i was trying using loop but it does not resetting the time to 300s

PS. Im not using loop on my example

what i want to do only is when the timer is Finish it will start again for no reason thats it.

what i want to do only is when the timer is Finish it will start again for no reason thats it.

Comment: Are you sure you want an infinite loop?

Comment: Please do not post source code as screen shot. Just copy and paste it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Similar question answered here in kotlin and java. You can review.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19997588/countdowntimer-in-android-how-to-restart-it)